# Array elements into variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
$data = array (                 
            'id'    => $_POST["id"],
            'name'  => $_POST["name"],
            'email' => $_POST["email"]
            );
```

Is there a single php function that can transform the array keys into variables having the value of the array value? For instance instead of echoing a value via `echo $data['name']` I can simply use `echo $name`.

Please do not suggest solutions using foreach loops (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extract` does just this: ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php))

```
 $size = "large";   
 $var_array = array("color" => "blue",
                       "size"  => "medium",
                       "shape" => "sphere");
 extract($var_array, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");

 echo "$color, $size, $shape, $wddx_size\n";
```

`list` does as well, in a more controlled fashion ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)), just note that **your source array must be numerically indexed** - no associative arrays allowed here:

```
    $info = array('coffee', 'brown', 'caffeine');

    // Listing all the variables
    list($drink, $color, $power) = $info;
    echo "$drink is $color and $power makes it special.\n";
```

Comment: Thanks! `extract()` seems to work. However I'm not sure if `list()` works with associative arrays.

Comment: You are correct sir, list is for numerically indexed arrays only. I will edit my answer to indicate that fact.

Answer (score 1):

```
extract($_POST);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: Please, please, please - do not run extract() directly on $_POST/$_GET/$_REQUEST

Comment: Agreed! Extract is already a kind of frustrating function for "Johnny Nextguy", running it on $_POST is a headache and a half to sort out.

Comment: Yep, I'd have to agree, it's not a great idea to do, but you can use it on any associative array

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.list.php

You're maybe looking for the list function, so you know which variable you are dealing with.

list($var, $var2) = $_POST;

Comment: As the OP pointed out, `list` is only valid for numerically indexed arrays.

Answer (score 1):

A foreach loop in this case is actually a pretty compact solution...

```
foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) { $$key = $value; }
```

Although, simply referencing the array by key is fairly tidy in and of itself...

```
echo $data['id'];
```

Comment: Why duplicate the functionality of `extract` with a foreach loop, and how is that compact considering there is a single function call available to accomplish the same result? Normally I wouldn't downvote over this kind of inefficiency, but in this case you came 10 minutes after `extract` was given as an answer (by several people) to suggest longer code that does the exact same thing... pointless.

Comment: I've always been told to stay away from `extract()`. As I understand there are some security concerns and removing it from use in general also removes the need for additional security concern or procedure.

Comment: You misunderstood then. Security issues with `extract()` are of the same sort that running PHP with `register_globals = On` option has. That's why in my comment above, I warned against running `extract()` directly on GPC arrays. However, if you learn how to use extra arguments `extract()` takes (especially the prefix one) you can feel perfectly safe.

Comment: I totally agree that extract should be avoided - it is a PITA for anyone other than yourself to update code when extract is used in some included file or global or some other nightmare. That was good advice you were given. ***However***, the take-away from that is not "avoid the function extract", the message is "avoid the outcome extract results in". So, if you do something like this code you've posted, then you're still conceptually using extract; you got the same result as you would have had you simply used the function instead of a loop.

Comment: It states in the php manual: `Do not use extract() on untrusted data` but if the data has been validated before used in `extract()` I think that it's safe, no?

Comment: @CyberJunkie: validation is not sanitation. In general make sure, that `extract()` will not overwrite any of your variables, that you would not like it to (like `$loggedAsAdmin` or something ;) ). With the rest deal like you would with any data that comes from userland.

Comment: Yes, you're safe using it on an array you made yourself.  Just be sure to add comments, don't use `extract`ed values across included files, and don't for Pete's sake make them global. Look - there's a lot of things people will tell you "NEVER DO XXX" or "XXX is harmful".  "Bad practice", they scream. This is all silly. If there's a feature in a language, there is an appropriate time and way to use it. Some features, like extract, must be used with caution because they are easy to misuse. That doesn't mean they have the plague. If they were so bad as all that, they wouldn't be in the language.

Comment: Even `eval()` is not evil sometimes ;P